# bash logic inside command substitution

Tags: bash, command-substitution, figlet

I have a little banner that I display at login

```
fignow() { figlet -w $(tput cols) $(date +"%b %d, Week %V"); figlet -w $(tput cols) -f univers $(date +"%H:%M"); }
```

This works fine if the additional fonts are installed to get `univers`, but that's not part of the default installation, so I can do the following:

```
fignow() { figlet -w $(tput cols) $(date +"%b %d, Week %V"); if [ -f /usr/share/figlet/univers.flf ]; then figlet -w $(tput cols) -f univers $(date +"%H:%M"); else figlet -w $(tput cols) $(date +"%H:%M"); fi; }
```

This also works fine, but I was curious if the `if/else/fi` could be removed and the logic could be done inside the command itself, i.e. something like:

```
fignow() { figlet -w $(tput cols) $(date +"%b %d, Week %V"); figlet -w $(tput cols) -f $(use-univers-or-failback-to-standard.flf-if-univers.flf-is-not-available) $(date +"%H:%M"); }
```

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `figlist` to avoid hardcoding the themes path:

```
figlet -w "$(tput cols)" -f "$((figlist | /bin/grep -hw universe) || echo "standard")" "foo"
```

Comment: I never knew `figlist` existed, that's nice to know. Relating to that, `figlist` shows the `.flc` files, like `moscow.flc` as if they are usable, but these are unreadable by `figlet`. i.e. `figlet -f moscow HelloWorld` says "unable to open font file". Do you know why `figlist` lists them as if they are usable?

Comment: @YorSubs: `moscow.flc` is no fontfile (.flf), it is a controlfile. See `man figlet` and its option `-C`.

Comment: @YorSubs Yeah, unfortunately there is no option to filter either the one other the other from figlist's output. But since you hardcode the name `universe` it shouldn't be an issue, right? I mean, figlist will at least tell you reliably if it's installed or not

Comment: This might help: `find $(figlet -I2) -name '*.flf'`

Comment: Cool. Pulling together various things in this thread, I got this down to `figlet -w $(tput cols) -f $([ -f $(figlet -I2)/univers.flf ] && echo "univers" || echo "standard") foo`. Any problems with this; is my logic correct that `&&` and `||` used like this works properly? Avoids relying on the `figlist` script and gets the font folder from `figlet -I2`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
fignow() {
  local opts
  figlet -w $(tput cols) $(date +"%b %d, Week %V")
  [ -f /usr/share/figlet/univers.flf ] && opts="-f univers"
  figlet -w $(tput cols) $opts $(date +"%H:%M")
}
```

Only if the file exists the variable $opts contains the necessary options.

Comment: This is a good approach, but will fail if opts is set outside the function.  You need to do: `fignow() { local opts=""; ....}`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Thanks for the hint, I have included it in my answer. I suggest to leave your comment here.

Answer (score 2):

Checking for the file or parsing the output of figlist or showfigfonts is inherently fragile.  Just call figlet to see if the option is available.  Something like:

```
fignow() {
        local font=${1-universe}
        figlet -f "$font" a > /dev/null 2>&1 || font=
        figlet -w $(tput cols) $(date +"%b %d, Week %V")
        figlet -w $(tput cols) ${font:+-f "$font"} $(date +"%H:%M")
}
```

Note that this is one of those cases where you *must not* use double quotes around the variable, since you want `${font:+-f "$font"}` to expand to the empty string when `$font` is empty.  If you use `"${font:+-f "$font"}"`, the semantics change and an empty string is passed to figlet.